# Continuing after failing a promise

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, promise

I have a case where a promise might fail, but I want to be able to handle that, and continue on to the next then.  I've tried to return a successful promise from within the fail catch, but it gives an error about the return object not having the method set.  Is this possible?  How would I go about it?

```
Parse.Promise.as(1).then(function() {

    if (user.get('vendor')) {
        //fetch returns a promise
        return user.get('vendor').fetch();
    }
    return new Vendor();

}).fail(function() {
    //this will be called if the fetch fails, in that case, just return new Vendor();
    return Parse.Promise.as(function() {
        //this will be a valid promise so should hopefully return to the next then, but it doesn't work
        return new Vendor();
    });
}).then(function(result) {
    vendor = result;
    //continue with stuff
}).fail(function(error) {
    res.json(400, {
        "result": false,
        "error": error
    });
});
```

EDIT:

I tried changing it to:

```
Parse.Promise.as(1).then(function() {

    if (user.get('vendor')) {
        return user.get('vendor').fetch();
    }
    return new Vendor();

}).then(null, function() {
    //if the fetch fails, this will return a successful Promise with Vendor object
    console.log("failed fetch");
    return new Vendor();
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("vendor retrieved");

}).then(null, function(error) {
    console.log('error');
});
```

But logged:
failed fetch
error

Is this just how Parse does it, or is something else wrong?

EDIT2:

Seems to work if I change the

```
return new Vendor();
```

line to

```
return Parse.Promise.as(1).then(function() { return new Vendor(); });
```

(edit) or this:

```
return Parse.Promise.as(new Vendor());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like you said, recovering from an exception is possible with promises:

```
try{
      mightThrow()
} catch (e){
     // handle
} 
thisWillRunRegardless();
```

Or with Parse promises:

```
Promise.as(1).then(function(){
    mightThrow();
}).then(null,function(e){
    // handle
}).then(function(){
    thisWillRunRegardless();
});
```

With other promise libraries it might look like:

```
Promise.try(function(){
     mightThrow();
}).catch(function(){
      //handle
]).then(thisWillRunRegardless);
```

The problem with your above code is the `.fail`. Since parse.com promises are jQuery complaint - their fail method acts like jQuery's. It adds a fail handler and *returns the same promise*.

Not sure why they did this, but oh well. You need to change `.fail(function(){` to `.then(null,function(){...` instead. The second argument  `.then` gets is the rejection handler.

Comment: Got it working, but it seems to require that the catching then returns a new promise.